# allow the two input checkbox behave the same with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked='true' />
<input type="checkbox" checked='true' />
```

Trying to use jQuery to allow the two inputs behave the same. If 1st checkbox is checked, 2nd is checked. If 1st is not checked, 2nd is not checked. And vise versa.

Code I have:

```
$('input:checkbox').live('change', function() {
  $('input:checkbox').siblings().prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Calling .live() instead of .on() here because I can only use jQuery 1.6.4

This works, but if I warp these input tags to two forms, it wont work anymore. Why? How do I fix this?

```
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" checked='true'/>
  </form>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" checked='true'/>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the siblings in your jQuery. So it should be:

```
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

After wrapping the `input` elements with `form` element, the input are no longer siblings. You can use `.siblings()` on the parent form, and then location the `input:checkbox` inside it:

```js
$('input:checkbox').live('change', function() {
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .siblings('form')
    .find('input:checkbox')
    .prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="example" checked='true' id="1" />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" class="example" checked='true' id="2" />
</form>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I cannot use class or id. Sorry, modified my OP.

Answer (score 0):

When you seperate checkbox elements from each other in the DOM and nest them in different elements, they are not siblings of each other anymore and the the JQuery method .siblings() will not return them.

Instead of relying on checkbox position, you can mark them using classes and then filter by class and set the checkbox value accordingly.

```
$('.example').live('change', function() {
  $('.example').prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Made a small JFiddle sample for you - https://jsfiddle.net/sa4eu86d/3/